# Last Netty 4.1 client blocked

Tags: java, netty

I have the following way of creating a `Netty 4.1` client:

```
public void runClient() throws Exception {
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
        final ClientClassHandler cch = new ClientClassHandler();
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();

        b.group(workerGroup);
        b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
        b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                ch.pipeline().addLast("frameDecoder",
                        new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());
                ch.pipeline().addLast("protobufDecoder",
                        new ProtobufDecoder(Client.MyMessage.getDefaultInstance()));
                ch.pipeline().addLast("frameEncoder", new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());
                ch.pipeline().addLast("protobufEncoder", new ProtobufEncoder());
                ch.pipeline().addLast("handler", cch);
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new CommonClassHandler());
            }
        });

        Player player = new Player();
        cch.setPlayer(player);
        player.createMap();

        Channel channel = b.connect(HOST, PORT).sync().channel();
        player.setChan(channel);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        // Waits for user input, then fills the Protocol Buffers build and sends it.
        while (channel.isOpen()) {
            String input = in.readLine();
            player.handleInput(input); // Checks if input is OK and sends it to server
        }

        channel.closeFuture().sync();

    } finally {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

But when a 4th client joins the server, the server launches a game loop and this loop seems to block the last client's input to reach the server.

The input is sent to the server like such:

```
  serverChannel.writeAndFlush(message.build());
```

But it never reaches the

```
  @Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    Server.MyMessage req = (Server.MyMessage) msg;

    protocol.handleInput(req, ctx); // Checks if input of client is OK
    System.out.println(req.getKeyword());
}
```

method and only does when the loop is stopped or inexistent.

I didn't think my server could be blocked like that because of a loop. Am I missing out on something?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused because you directly start the game loop from the `channelRead` method.

As long as 1 thread is in the `channelRead` method, no other inputs can be accepted to that channel by netty to prevent ordering and thread safety bugs.

You should either spawn a custom thread to handle your game loop, or hook into the group's event executor to get a dedicated thread for your loop.